# Cannot open "idle" in root mode using python

Tags: python

I am trying blink an LED using some python code, but the problem is I am unable to run the `idle` in root mode, i.e., when I type `sudo idle` in the `lxterminal` it's showing errors such as

```
PuTTy X11 proxy: Unsupported authorisation protocol
```

and some more.

[image: this the error that I am getting when I have tried to run idle in root mode]

Comment: This looks like your error and solution. http://superuser.com/a/592190/463646

Answer (score 1):

You can not open programs that uses `GUI` via ssh. Use remote desktop using a decent vnc or xrdp as per your platform. You can make use of plain `python` shell by issuing `sudo python` and start executing your code.

---

Edit:

You can make use of `ssh -X ..` if you're using linux. and use `export DISPLAY=:0` before issuing GUI commands to make it work on your original display.

For windows (PuTTy), you will have to enable X11 forwarding support.

Hope it helps.

Comment: ssh -X may work.

Comment: He said he is using lxterminal, doesn't it mean he does it locally? After all lxterm (or lxterminal) is GUI app, right?

Comment: @PiotrKamoda He mentioned putty in his question. Even though he mentioned `lxterminal`, my guess is, he is connecting it via ssh. Again, it's my guess. Also, It is very common error for guys trying to execute a GUI program via remote access.

Comment: actually am using a laptop without a hdmi cable to connect to the raspberry pi so i am using putty and even i hav an other problem i dont get any icons as i get acess to raspberry (i.e)as the window opens i will only get the logo of raspberry in the middle and nothng else. to get acess to it i left click ooon the screen and create a new folder and then acess the apllications through that folder.

Comment: @SharathVedala If you want to use python shell, you can do it on your ssh by issuing `sudo python`. IDLE is similar shell with good graphics and everything.

Comment: @SharathVedala Again, `sudo` part is not necessary but if you're playing with GPIO, serial etc, you will need `sudo`

Comment: yes iam unable to access GPIO thats my problem

Comment: @SharathVedala You need to use "sudo".

Comment: As u said i have used "sudo python"  and i can use it.But how can i get access to  GPIO.If u have any link in reference how to use GPIO pls provide me that.

Comment: @SharathVedala What do you mean by "access to GPIO" ? Are you talking about RPi.GPIO or using physical GPIO pins of pi ? For both of them, there are plenty of guides available.

Comment: i want to use this code for blinking led

Comment: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/raspberry-gpio/python-rpigpio-example

Comment: i want to use this code for blinking LED for that i need to use the library RPi.GPIO as GPIO in the idle software and  make one of the GPIO as out put and use few commands to finish it .But can i do this in the "sudo python" or i know to do this by using "sudo idle" but its not working

Comment: Yes, both are python shell.

Comment: i am able to b;ink led as per the link in "learn.sparkfun.com". thanks for that dastaan.

Comment: Can u please provide me a tutorial or a link for learning programming

Comment: @SharathVedala You're welcome. May be you would like to upvote an answer. :)

Comment: @SharathVedala Google is your friend. :)

Answer (score 0):

Like the folks above have said, you can run python from PuTTY by simply running `sudo python` and this will solve being able to run python in text mode from your Windows system.  And to control LEDs that's all you need.

The error you are getting has to do with Windows not being able to open a GUI program running on your RPi.  If you really wanted to see your RPi's GUI apps on Windows you can do this by running an X11 server (the Linux GUI system) on your Windows system.  Check out [the xming project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/) and [instructions for using it with PuTTY](https://wiki.utdallas.edu/wiki/display/FAQ/X11+Forwarding+using+Xming+and+PuTTY).